# Why does BigInteger parse "80"(hex) to two bytes?

Tags: java, hex, biginteger

I want to convert a hex-string to a byte-array. I thought using `BigInteger` is a good idea. But for values greater than `7F` it produces unexpected results.

My code:

```
    var bytes = new BigInteger("80", 16).toByteArray();
    for (var b : bytes) System.out.println(b);
```

It outputs:

```
0
-128
```

Why does this produce **two** bytes?

I would have expected `00` to `FF` to produce one byte, `0100` to `FFFF` to produce two bytes, and so forth.

---

Side note: The first byte seems to actually matter:

```
new BigInteger(new byte[]{      (byte)0x80}); // produces -128 (negative!)
new BigInteger(new byte[]{   0, (byte)0x80}); // produces  128
new BigInteger(new byte[]{0, 0, (byte)0x80}); // produces  128
```

Comment: Using a single byte for 0–FF works (only) if you don’t allow negative values. But `BigInteger` *does* allow negative values.

Comment: I would say : because `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal` and others are made to work with real digits (they are made for mathematical calculation to avoid problems of `float`, `double`  types with their remainders, if I remember well...) and when you store in them "80" in base 16, `BigInteger` might understand "8" and "0".

Comment: How can you represent both negative and positive integers in one byte array? BigInteger does this the same way that ASN.1 does it for DER-encoded integers, but without the tag and length header bytes of ASN.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all Your contributions, comments and answers, finally I understand what is going on.

Numbers from 0 to Hex 0x7F (decimal 127) work like this:

```
First Bit=sign (0=+,1=-)
|    Other bits=number
v    vvv vvvv
0    111 1111    = 0x7F = 127
```

Numbers from 128 to Hex 0x7FFF (decimal 32.767) work like this:

```
First Bit (of first byte!)=sign
|    Other bits and other bytes=number
v    vvv vvvv vvvv vvvv
0    000 0000 1000 0000    = 0x80 = 128
```

Long story short:

- Only **the first bit of the first byte** is determining the sign
- All other bits of all other bytes determine the absolute value

  - That is 7 bits of the first byte
  - And 8 bits of every other byte

Answer (score 3):

Because BigInteger is signed.

You specified `"80"` in hex, and you didn't specify that it is negative; therefore the highest bit (in two's complement) must be zero. If you try to represent `80` in one byte, then the top bit is 1, so it would be negative.

If you try `new BigInteger("-80", 16).toByteArray()` then you get one byte, with the value `-128`.

Comment: But why is the first byte `0x00`, not `0x01`?

Comment: Why should it be 1? `0080` (hex) is a correct two's complement representation of 128. `0180` is not.

Comment: I expected `0080` to be equal to `80` (which it is not). That is kind of suprising, isn't it?

Comment: @slartidan Yes, I agree it is surprising if you don't know it's using two's complement.

Comment: Just as `0x80` in a `byte` variable has a different value from `0x00000080` in an `int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

the `toByteArray()` method returns a byte array containing the two's-complement
representation of this BigInteger.  The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order

the method internally looks like:

```
public byte[] toByteArray() {
    int byteLen = bitLength()/8 + 1;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteLen];
    for (int i=byteLen-1, bytesCopied=4, nextInt=0, intIndex=0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (bytesCopied == 4) {
            nextInt = getInt(intIndex++);
            bytesCopied = 1;
        } else {
            nextInt >>>= 8;
            bytesCopied++;
        }
        byteArray[i] = (byte)nextInt;
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

so as you can see

```
int byteLen = bitLength()/8 + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation of `toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) says

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger.

[Two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) stores the sign bit in the highest order bit. As a consequence, signed, positive values from 0x0–0x7F (that is, 0000 0000–0111 1111 in binary) only require a single byte to store, but values greater than that require a second byte, since they’d otherwise denote a negative value. In particular, 1000 0000 (which, when *unsigned*, can be written as 0x80) corresponds to the value −0x80, not +0x80, in two’s complement.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.